# Radio Button not working exclusively and giving error in MATLAB GUI

Tags: matlab, matlab-gui

I am writing a code for MATLAB GUI for pair comparison of images but i am stuck because my radio button are not working exclusivley

```
gui_Singleton = 1;
gui_State = struct('gui_Name',       mfilename, ...
                   'gui_Singleton',  gui_Singleton, ...
                   'gui_OpeningFcn', @GUI_Personality_Impressions_OpeningFcn, ...
                   'gui_OutputFcn',  @GUI_Personality_Impressions_OutputFcn, ...
                   'gui_LayoutFcn',  [] , ...
                   'gui_Callback',   []);
if nargin && ischar(varargin{1})
    gui_State.gui_Callback = str2func(varargin{1});
end

if nargout
    [varargout{1:nargout}] = gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
else
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});
end
% End initialization code - DO NOT EDIT


% --- Executes just before GUI_Personality_Impressions is made visible.
function GUI_Personality_Impressions_OpeningFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles, varargin)
% This function has no output args, see OutputFcn.
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
% varargin   command line arguments to GUI_Personality_Impressions (see VARARGIN)

% Choose default command line output for GUI_Personality_Impressions
handles.output = hObject;

% Update handles structure
guidata(hObject, handles);

% UIWAIT makes GUI_Personality_Impressions wait for user response (see UIRESUME)
% uiwait(handles.figure1);


% --- Outputs from this function are returned to the command line.
function varargout = GUI_Personality_Impressions_OutputFcn(hObject, eventdata, handles) 
% varargout  cell array for returning output args (see VARARGOUT);
% hObject    handle to figure
% eventdata  reserved - to be defined in a future version of MATLAB
% handles    structure with handles and user data (see GUIDATA)
set(handles.axes1,'units','pixels');
set(handles.axes2,'units','pixels');
scrz=get(0,'ScreenSize')
% pos2=[(scrz(3)-800)/2  (scrz(4)-600)/2 800 600];
fig_hr = 326;
fig_vr = 493;


pos1 = round((scrz(3)-fig_hr)/4)
pos2 = round((scrz(4)-fig_vr)/2)

% fig_xcoord = (ScreenSize(3) - fig_width)/2; 

pos3 = [pos1 pos2 fig_hr fig_vr]
set(handles.axes1,'pos',[pos3]);
axes(handles.axes1);  
imshow('Chinese_eyes+2.tif');
% pos1 = round((scrz(3)-fig_hr)/  3)
posa = pos1 +1.5* round(fig_hr);
pos4 = [posa pos2 fig_hr fig_vr]
set(handles.axes2,'pos',[pos4]);
axes(handles.axes2);
imshow('Chinese_eyes+2.tif');
% % Get default command line output from handles structure
varargout{1} = handles.output;


% handles.FigureH = figure;
handles.radio1 = uicontrol('Style', 'radiobutton', ...
                           'Callback', @myRadio, ...
                           'Units',    'pixels', ...
                           'Tag',      'A1', ...
                           'Position', [(pos1+326+pos1)/2, pos2-70,70 ,50 ], ...
                           'String',   'A', ...                           
                           'Value',    1);
handles.radio2 = uicontrol('Style', 'radiobutton', ...
                           'Callback', @myRadio, ...
                           'Units',    'pixels', ...
                           'Position', [(posa+326+posa)/2, pos2-70,70 ,50], ...
                           'String',   'B', ...
                           'Tag',      'B1', ...
                           'Value',    0);

%  handles.Next= uicontrol('Style', 'pushbutton', ...
%                            'Callback', @pushbutton1, ...                           
%                            'Units',    'pixels', ...
%                            'Position', [(((pos1+326+pos1)/2)+(posa+326+posa)/2)/2, pos2- 140,70 ,50 ], ...
%                            'String',   'Next', ...
%                            'Value',    0);                    
% set(handles.Next,'Enable','off')                       

guidata(hObject, handles);



function myRadio(hObject,eventdata, handles)
global data

switch get(hObject,'Tag') % Get Tag of selected object.
    case 'A1'
       data=1;
        set(handles.radio2, 'Value', 0);
    case 'B1'
       data=2;    
      set(handles.radio1, 'Value',0);


end
```

and when on the GUI I select a radio button following errors appear

"Not enough input arguments.

Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback."

The error is on the line for set i.e.set(handles.radio2, 'Value', 0);

I need help in this regard...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, if you want your radio buttons to operate together (only be able to select one), you want to put them into a [`uibuttongroup`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/uibuttongroup.html).

Second, the reason for your error is because the *standard* MATLAB callbacks (the ones defined with `uicontrol(..., 'Callback', @callback, ...)`) only pass *two* input arguments (compared to 3 for GUIDE GUIs).

These inputs are:

1. The object that generated the callback (the handle to your button)
2. Any associated event data

So you will want to modify `myRadio` to accept two input arguments.

```
function myRadio(hObject, eventData)

    switch get(hObject,'Tag') % Get Tag of selected object.
        case 'A1'
            set(handles.radio2, 'Value', 0);
        case 'B1'
            set(handles.radio1, 'Value',0);
    end
end
```

The other option is to manually designate the inputs to your callback function using an [anonymous function](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/anonymous-functions.html). You could use this to create a callback with three inputs (just like GUIDE's own callbacks) and then your `myRadio` function could remain as you have it.

```
set(handles.radio1, 'Callback', @(src,evnt)myRadio(src, evnt, handles))
```

All that aside, if you use a `uibuttongroup`, you won't *need* this callback since all it does is ensures that only one radio button is selected at a time.

Comment: Thank you ... I am facing few errors while using switch statement using push button but the issue of radio button working exclusively is solved... Thank you